# Restructure huge unnormalized mysql database part 2

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, database-schema, amazon-rds

I have a unnormalized database with ~400 million rows, I have moved all repeating data into a new normalized database so I can represent it with id's.

Now I need to move all the data entrys and transform it to a entry containing id's.

The problem is that with 400m row it will take a while.. and i need help to optimize.

This query takes 0.4 sec per row, so it would take a few months:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO normalized.entry (insDate, `date`, project, keyword, url, position, competition, serachEngine)
SELECT 
CURDATE() as insDate
, d.id as dateId
, p.id as projectId
, k.id as keywordId
, z.id AS urlId 
, old.position
, old.competition
, s.id as searchEngineId

FROM unnormalized.bigtable old
INNER JOIN normalized.`date` d  ON old.insDate = d.`date`
INNER JOIN normalized.project p ON old.awrProject = p.project
INNER JOIN normalized.searchEngine s ON old.searchEngine = s.searchEngine
INNER JOIN normalized.keyword k ON old.keyword = k.keyword
INNER JOIN normalized.urlHash z ON old.url = z.url
WHERE old.id >= ".$start." AND old.id <= ".$stop."";
```

If I use more php and divide it into two querys do it this way it takes only 0.07sec per entry but still that's also takes months:

```
$q = "SELECT tmp.id
              , d.id as dateId
              , p.id as projectId
              , k.id as keywordId
              , tmp.position
              , tmp.competition
              , s.id as searchEngineId
              , tmp.url
              , z.id AS urlId 
               FROM unnormalized.bigtable tmp
        INNER JOIN normalized.`date` d ON tmp.insDate = d.`date`
        INNER JOIN normalized.project p ON tmp.awrProject = p.project
        INNER JOIN normalized.searchEngine s ON tmp.searchEngine = s.searchEngine
        INNER JOIN normalized.keyword k ON tmp.keyword = k.keyword
        INNER JOIN normalized.urlHash z ON tmp.url = z.url
        WHERE tmp.id > ".$start." AND tmp.id < ".$stop."";
        // echo $q;
            $result = mysql_query($q, $local);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $q = "SELECT id FROM normalized.url WHERE url = '".$row["url"]."'";
            $resultUrl = mysql_query($q, $local);
            $rowUrl = mysql_fetch_array($resultUrl);

            $q = "INSERT IGNORE normalized.entry (insDate, `date`, project, keyword, url, position, competition, serachEngine) VALUES (NOW(), '".$row["dateId"]."', '".$row["projectId"]."', '".$row["keywordId"]."', '".$rowUrl["id"]."', '".$row["position"]."', '".$row["competition"]."', '".$row["searchEngineId"]."')";
```

I don't know how I am gonna port this data without it taking half a year!
/All help it needed

spec: Am using  InnoDB on a RDS amazon server.

edit: EXPLAIN SELECT of the first query:

id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,p,index,NULL,projectName,42,NULL,1346,"Using index"
1,SIMPLE,s,index,NULL,searchEngine,42,NULL,2336,"Using index; Using join buffer"
1,SIMPLE,k,index,NULL,keyword,42,NULL,128567,"Using index; Using join buffer"
1,SIMPLE,tmp,ref,"keyword_url_insDate,keyword,searchEngine,url,awrProject",keyword_url_insDate,767,func,115,"Using where"
1,SIMPLE,d,eq_ref,date,date,3,intradb.tmp.insDate,1,"Using where; Using index"
1,SIMPLE,z,ref,url,url,767,bbointradb.tmp.url,1,"Using index"

SHOW CREATE TABLE:

'rankingUrls201001', 'CREATE TABLE `rankingUrls201001` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `insDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `searchEngine` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `competition` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `awrProject` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `server` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `rank` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `keyword_url_insDate` (`keyword`,`url`,`insDate`),
  KEY `keyword` (`keyword`),
  KEY `searchEngine` (`searchEngine`),
  KEY `url` (`url`),
  KEY `awrProject` (`awrProject`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2266575 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci'

Comment: What is the schema of the tables? (the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`)

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN your_select_query` (the SELECT query used by the first INSERT query in your question)?

Comment: I have added the output of EXPLAIN to the bottom of the post.

Comment: Moving repeating data into another table so you can represent it with id numbers is done, in part, to increase the number of joins you need. It doesn't have anything to do with normalization. (There's no such thing as "replace text with ID numbers" normal form.)

Comment: I know, but removing all repeating data is nice, i am aiming for 3 normal form.

Answer (score 0):

@Robin, in order to speed up the data transfer process you should take the proper steps to ensure all processing is done in-memory as well as you should avoid any WRITEs to disk as much as you possibly can.
If you do the following steps, the file transfer processing time should be reduced:

1. First, configure your DB instance to have as much temporary workspace allocated as possible.
2. Second, split the process into a multiple-step process, so that each processing phase will be completed with minimum WRITE to disk activities.
3. Finally, disable the binary log; this will reduce WRITE to disk processing, which in many cases can reduce query response times by as much as half.

These steps should speed up the process, but taking into account the amount of data rows you have, it still might take a certain amount of time to transfer and process.